# Drupal, set dynamically css

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7

Does anyone know how to set dynamical css in a Drupal 7 theme? Depending on the browser I want to choose one or another file.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How about this?: https://drupal.org/node/744328

Comment: @Cheesebaron That is for Internet Explorer. The other browsers would get the same CSS: the one not for Internet Explorer browsers.

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention which browsers you wanted to support. Anyways, there are several projects that will give the same end result as you want. Check out: https://drupal.org/project/browserclass and https://drupal.org/project/browscap

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Browser class](http://drupal.org/project/browserclass) module, and the [Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) module. These projects will lead to a result that does what you want.

> This small module helps theme-developers to deal with cross-browser compatibility. It makes easier to handle different types of non-widespread browsers just as much as it helps with using different versions of Internet Explorer.
>   The module extends the $body_classes variable in page.tpl.php based on the enduser's browser, and platform.

> Browscap provides an improved version of PHP's `get_browser()` function.
>
> The `get_browser()` function can be used to tell what a visitor's browser is capable of. Unfortunately, the version provided by PHP has a number of limitations, namely:
>
> - It can be difficult or impossible to configure for shared hosting environments.
> - The data used to identify browsers and determine their capabilities requires consistent maintenance to keep up-to-date.
>
> Browscap automates maintenance by storing browser data in a database and automatically retrieving the latest data on a configurable schedule.